# Create many generic types with similar shape

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I'd like to create a TypeScript generic, that **creates** a type for me which has a generic input with a (extends) constraint.
I don't want to specify the constraint everywhere since I want to create a lot of types with a similar shape.

I want something like this (kinda pseudocode)

```
type CreateMyType<A extends Constraint> = ...

type MyCustomType = CreateMyType<A>

MyCustomType<T> // T can only extend Constraint without specifying here
```

Is this possible? I though of maybe with infer keyword and never, but I want the autocompletion also to work for the type parameter of MyCustomType.

Any tips to accomplish a similar behavior?

Comment: There is no shorthand for generic constraints, so on the face of it the answer here is "no this impossible".  As for "similar behavior" I think I'd need to see a [mre] and not just pseudocode to make suggestions (but I doubt there's anything more ergonomic than just repeating your constraints everywhere).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can create a small example on ts playground